# Can Visual Studio 2017 support multiple SDKs for UWP (Windows 10)?

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

Background: I downloaded Visual Studio 2017 and installed the latest SDK ("10.0.17763.0"). I then proceeded to download the Windows 10 October 2018 Update. I discovered that there were problems with this version, that have since been corrected but I am no longer was comfortable using it only a few weeks after its release, so I did not download it. When I preceded to create a UWP app and attempted to look at the XAML, I got the following error: "Visual Studio requires a newer version of windows to display this content". I did some research and discovered that I could change the target version by going to "Properties > Application > Target:". When I clicked on the drop down arrow, there was only one selection, the SDK I had initially installed. I need the previous version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. Open Visual Studio Installer.
3. Update if necessary, then click "Modify".
4. At the top click "Individual Components".
5. Scroll down and look for the header "SDK's libraries and frameworks".
6. Check the additional SDK you need, note storage requirements and proceed.
7. Bring up VS2017, go to "Properties > Application > Target:" and select the SDK.